# flutter error in running app in andriod studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I have installed Android studio with the latest Jdk version and flutter SDK and configured it to my studio by installing flutter and dart plugin but when I run the sample code it doesn't run properly and shows some errors.
I am a newbie to programming so plz tell me solution how to fix that error and I also attached a screenshot of that error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWAKn.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see here [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, it would be great if instead of adding pictures, you add error here directly.

Comment: There is an `UnknownhostException` in the errors, **connect to the internet** and let the plugins and Android Studio update. Also the gradle plugin might need to connect to the internet.

Comment: Seems like your development device is disconnected from internet while building the app

Comment: Prasanna kumar you're right i disconnected from internet while building the app how to build app without internet bro plzz reply me